# Subset a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Intid   Ref RegNum  Vetted  Name    Value
1       x   A1      Yes     A       45
1       x   A1      Yes     B       168
1       x   A1      Yes     C       303
2       x   A1      No      A       45
2       x   A1      No      B       85
2       x   A1      No      C       280
3       y   B2      No      A       23
3       y   B2      No      F       50
```

How can I subset it so that the data frame will look like this; meaning that keeping the data which is vetted `Yes` only for `RegNum` with `Vetted`  values `Yes` and `No`, and the data of `RegNum` with `No` value only?

```
Intid   Ref RegNum  Vetted  Name    Value
1       x   A1      Yes     A       45      
1       x   A1      Yes     B       168     
1       x   A1      Yes     C       303   
3       y   B2      No      A       23
3       y   B2      No      F       50
```

Comment: You are getting downvoted because your textual description makes no sense. Please try again... maybe it would help if you use pseudo mathematical language... like `(condition1 AND condition2) BUT NOT condition3`

Answer (score 1):

One idea with `dplyr` can be,

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
 group_by(RegNum) %>% 
 filter(Vetted == 'Yes'|all(Vetted == 'No'))

#Source: local data frame [5 x 6]
#Groups: RegNum [2]

#  Intid    Ref RegNum Vetted   Name Value
#  <int> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <int>
#1     1      x     A1    Yes      A    45
#2     1      x     A1    Yes      B   168
#3     1      x     A1    Yes      C   303
#4     3      y     B2     No      A    23
#5     3      y     B2     No      F    50
```